# angular 2 http.get subscribe: How to call another function when service completed?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, angular2-services

Don't get it. If I need my result to do something more, not just enter my variable heros for example. I want to call another function on success or completed but I just can't. Why is that and how it should be done? I have another variable need to be getting the same data returned from the response (copy of it), but I can make the copy only after I get the data.

```
this.myService.getHeroes()
    .subscribe(
        function(response) {
            response => this.heros = response;
        },
        function(error) {
            console.log("Error happened" + error)
        },
        function() {
            console.log("the subscription is completed");
        }
    );
```

Comment: To begin with your syntax is wrong, that will not transpile. You want `(response) => this.heros = response;` and **not** a combination of `function` and the arrow function.

Comment: 10x I currect it but still the same issue. like I can not call any other function from inside the success/error/complete functions

Comment: First you have to define a function then call it/:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call the function just after you get the response.

```js
this.myService.getHeroes()
   .subscribe(res => {
      this.heros = res;
      //insert whatever you want here, e.g. function which needs to wait for asynchro response
    },
    error => { 
      console.log("Error happened" + error)
    }
 );
```

Comment: Nope, I get error that yourFunction isn't a function

Comment: @AngularOne I have just called it as an example... You can insert whatever you want there, e.g. some of your functions, which have to wait for the asynchronous response. You can also just delete it.

Comment: @AngularOne @Kinduser is right. You should call your ``function`` after ``this.heroes = res``. Observable ``complete`` function calling when ``Observer`` ends operation with Observable. But what if it doesn't? Maybe this stream is infinite, then ``complete`` never called

Comment: got it now. What comes after the error, another function of completed?

Comment: @AngularOne Inside the `error` function our after it?

Comment: You wrote 2 finction: success and error. Where is the complete function goes in?

Comment: @AngularOne Of course in the success. Error function gets started only if any error has occured.

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon what such a Kind user provided:

The reason you are unable to access your other component variables is because the `this` keyword's scope is encapsulated to within the function only and no longer knows about component variables.

In order to reference component variables, you must utilize lambda expressions instead:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-browse',
  templateUrl: './browse.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./browse.component.css']
})
export class BrowseComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private myService: MyService) { }

  myString: string = 'dogs';

  doStuff() {
    this.myService.doMoreStuff().subscribe(returnValue => {
      console.log(this.myString); // 'dogs'
      this.myOtherFunction(); // 'other stuff'
    });

    this.myService.doMoreStuff().subscribe(function(returnValue) {
      console.log(this.myString); // undefined
      // myString does not exist with the scope of this function
      var myString = 'cats';
      console.log(this.myString); // 'cats'
    });
  }

  myOtherFunction() { console.log('otherStuff'); }

}
```